# Some button clicks not executed in a section periodically updated by jQuery.load()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a website where one part is very often (multiple times a second) updated using ajax requests (via the jQuery.load method).
In the regulary updated part of the website are jquery ui buttons. Sometimes (in ~10% of the cases) the click on these buttons is not executed. My guess would be that this is some timing issue with the replacement of the html. Therefore my question: how can I ensure all button clicks are properly executed?

It's not an option to update a smaller part of the website (excluding the buttons) but it's possible to pause the site update. But pausing it when hovering a button is also no option as this would potentially prevent the update for too long.

Thanks in advance

---

The Button Code which is regulary loaded looks like this:

```
<input type="button" id="buttonID">
<script>
        $("#buttonID").button({ label: 'Button Label' }).click(function() {
            // some logic
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try assigning all your buttons a CSS class, and binding your click handler with `$(".button_class").on("click", function() { .. })`?

Comment: I added to my question a snippet of the code I use to create the button. Which is regulary reloaded. 
I don't think that the binding itself is the problem as the script tag is directly after the button html and therefor the parser should execute it in that order and therefore when the button is visible it should also have the click method bound to it.

Comment: As you are loading new content dynamically, you will need to assign this through `.on()`. You could also reload and refresh `.button()` and `.click()` after the content is loaded.

Comment: The codesnippet I added is completely loaded everytime (including the script part). the script part is executed when loading the snippet with the jQuery.load() method. So I actually "refresh" the button and click everytime it's loaded.

Comment: The Issue is not that it isn't working at all the issue is just that some clicks are lost. So I can click the button in ~90% of the cases.